# RegEx to remove bbcode tag nested within bbcode tag

Tags: php, regex, nested, bbcode

I need to prepare a regular expression that can be used to remove a bbcode [QUOTE]
 (examples: [QUOTE=name]; [QUOTE=123;123]) tag, when it is nested within a pre-existing [QUOTE] tag.

The current regular expression I am using is from the answer here (full explanation of the regex included): [Remove nested quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754062/remove-nested-quotes)

```
~\G(?!\A)(?>(\[quote\b[^]]*](?>[^[]+|\[(?!/?quote)|(?1))*\[/quote])|(?<!\[)(?>[^[]+|\[(?!/?quote))+\K)|\[quote\b[^]]*]\K~
```

However, this only removes a second or later nested [QUOTE] tag, but leaves a single nested tag, I now want to have all [QUOTE] tags removed if they are nested within an existing [QUOTE] tag.

An example of an input and how it should output from `preg_replace()`:

```
//input
$string = 'Here is a quote [QUOTE=person]I am also quoting [QUOTE]this is a nested quote[/QUOTE][/QUOTE]';

//preg replace
$string = preg_replace('regular_expression', '', $string);

//output
echo $string;
// Here is a quote [QUOTE=person]I am also quoting[/QUOTE]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove nested quotes](//stackoverflow.com/q/18754062)

Comment: @mario That is the regex that I have displayed above, that I was previously using

Comment: I know. Which brings up a few questions. Why not mention so beforehand? Why pick the least readable one? And what adaptations have you tried? Right now this is just a repost without new context. So why not post a bounty on the original question simply?

Comment: I've added it in now. What do you mean the least readable one? That is the only solution there that works properly. It is with new context, the solution I am looking for is not the same as the other post.

Comment: Okay my mistake, with the link to the source I don't see the benefit in me copy pasting that explanation now

Comment: Maybe `https://regex101.com/r/4vlEs4/1` will be enough? This will remove all nested QUOTEs inside an outer QUOTE. To remove all nested occurrences, you will need to replace with an empty string until no  match is found.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive approach:

```
(\[QUOTE[^][]*\])
(
    (?:[^][]+|(?R))+
)
\[/QUOTE\]
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/gfMRz6/1/).

---

In `PHP` this would be:

```
$regex = '~
        (\[QUOTE[^][]*\])
        (
            (?:[^][]+|(?R))+
        )
        (\[/QUOTE\])
        ~x';

$string = 'Here is a quote [QUOTE=person]I am also quoting [QUOTE]this is a nested quote[/QUOTE][/QUOTE]';

$string = preg_replace_callback($regex, 
    function($match) {
        return $match[1] . preg_replace('~\[/?[^][]*\]~', '', $match[2]) . $match[3];
    },
    $string);

echo $string;
?>
```

---

This yields

```
Here is a quote [QUOTE=person]I am also quoting this is a nested quote[/QUOTE]
```